# extracting matching regex value as column in sql

Tags: sql, regex, databricks, databricks-sql

I have a column with a long string and I want to extract some matching values from string as column in SQL 
I have **content** column which contains string in below format

```
workflow:myToPath{|}mypath:/add-products{amp}items[0][id]=AB6C4GBCT34DBBNGTLO{amp}valueid=AB3ESHQY{|}source:Gen:all:GenCard{|}guid:xxxx-xxx-xxxx{|}pascode:ABCD{|}version:14.0.12
```

I want to extract
`valueid`, `source`, `pascode`, `version` as columns from **content_column** which contains above sample strings
I tried `regexp_extract(content_action, 'promoid=\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w',0)`, but this is returning blank

Answer (score 0):

There are a few changes that you need to make:

- You must write a regex that matches the whole string - add `.*` before and after your matching data. Something like this

```sql
egexp_extract(column, '.*version:(.*)', 1)
```

- You need to define a capture group around your match using `()`
- References to the capture groups are starting with `1`, not with 0

I would recommend using a site like [this](https://regex101.com/) to test your regular expressions - you need to use Java dialect there.

Comment: When I am trying `.*source:(.*?\{)` to extract only source content it is giving me error in databricks SQL

Comment: try something like this: `.*source:([^{]+)\{`

Answer (score 0):

For reference, you can use the following *capture pattern*, to evaluate the *key* and *value*.

The first group is the key, and the second is the value.

```
(valueid|(?:source|pascode|version))[=:](.+?)(?=\{|$)
```